# How can the back button for inappbrowser be disabled?

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins

I am creating web app using phonegap with the inappbrowser, that has the feature of disabling the back button. According to its specification on how to disable the backbutton it is supposed to be implemented this way

```
function fire(){
  var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr', '_blank',  'location=no','zoom=no','hardwareback=no', 'clearsessioncache=no', 'clearcache=yes');
```

But whenever I compile my app and install the inappbrowser still has the ability to go back when I have checked pages.

Is there any other way of disabling this back button?

I am working with phonegap 3.4.0

The plugin: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/4121

I am working with the build version of phonegap

Answer (score 1):

To completely disable the back button functionality you can override it in Java.

1.) Disable the back button in your MainActivity.java class by overriding onBackPressed function:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Do Here what ever you want do on back press;
}
```

2.) Do the same within inappbrowser package => InAppBrowserDialog.java (the function already exists there, just delete everything within the onBackPressed function.

Answer (score 0):

The correct form to call the method is:

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr', '_blank',  'location=no,zoom=no,hardwareback=no,clearsessioncache=no,clearcache=yes');
```

But this do not disable the back button, only will make the back button close de inappbrowser.